# Issue adding GUI to Ubuntu server

Tags: server, gui

I recently installed Ubuntu Server LTS 16.04.3. I decided to add a minimal GUI using the command commonly recommended for doing so:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

What I got was a GUI that doesn't recognize any commands. I can't even get a terminal window to appear. Typing any text in the Search bar results in "Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search", regardless of what I enter. The installation is now essentially useless because I can't initiate any actions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have any of the underlying software needed to run in a desktop environment due to `--no-install-recommends`

Comment: I don't know your reasoning for installing a desktop, but there are web based graphical front ends for server management that may better serve your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use a GUI on your server for testing and learning purposes, i.e. not in production where you shouldn't have X installed at all, try using something lighter like XFCE.

You don't have any of the underlying software needed to run in a desktop environment due to `--no-install-recommends`

You can either install the full desktop with recomended software for unity/ubuntu-desktop by repeating your step without `--no-install-recommends`

or

if you want to try XFCE you can

`sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-desktop`

then

`sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies`

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm not sure why so many people recommend using the "--no-install-recommends" option, then, resulting as it does in a dysfunctional interface.